# Conversion date stored as characters into date format in R

Tags: r, date

I am trying to convert charters like this 01.1.2012 into Date format in R. But unfortunately when I try to convert characters function 'Date' is convert this characters into NA.

```
Df<-data.frame(
  Date="01.01.2012")

Df$Date<-as.Date(Date)
```

After execution of this piece of code I receive this message:

```
Error in as.Date.default(Date) : 
  do not know how to convert 'Date' to class “Date”
```

Can anybody help me how to convert this charters into date format in R?

Comment: `Df$Date <- as.Date(Df$Date, '%d.%m.%Y')` Or use `Df$Date <- lubridate::dmy(Df$Date)`

Comment: It is not in standard form. Does the first 01 stand for day?